# invalid MySQL argument in mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, fetch

`Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /rideanddrive/_classes/__base.php on line 45`

My code :

```
public static function SelectSpecific($obj, $data_base, $cond)
{
    self::$query = "select $obj from " . self::$baseprefix . "$data_base where $cond";
    $out = self::Execute();
    $array = mysql_fetch_array($out); // THIS LINE IS WARNING LINE
    return $array[$obj];
}
```

Execute function, if needed :

```
private static function Execute() 
{
    $out = mysql_query(self::$query);
    return $out;
}
```

Code's works fine. I don't get a warning on localhost (running WAMP, might have turned them off ?), it also works on live server, however I'm getting the above warning, how do I correct it so the warning is gone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Your **SelectSpecific** function embed a `if` check  to see your **execute** function returning proper resource for result .. if not then echo your sql then run it on server separately so that if you can find a error if there is any error with sql ,here is the updated function with `if` embedded

```
public static function SelectSpecific($obj, $data_base, $cond)
    {
        self::$query = "select $obj from " . self::$baseprefix . "$data_base where $cond";
        $out = self::Execute();
        if($out){
          $array = mysql_fetch_array($out); // THIS LINE IS WARNING LINE
          return $array[$obj];
       }else {
         return false;
       }
    }
```

Comment: @Abbys: Note, that this makes the error message not appear any more, but - of course - it does not fix the error in your SQL query.

Comment: @Callidior - thanks for the comment. However, this is an warning, not an error. The query itself works fine, it collects the data I wanted and returns it just fine. Or am I just missing something here ?

Comment: @Abbys: If you implemented it as in the answer above, no data is returned, but `false` in this case. So, there is at least one erroneous query. You have just added an explicit check, whether it was successful or not. If not, you don't even call `mysql_fetch_array`, which produced the warning; but you won't collect any data this way too.

Answer (score 1):

This warning indicates, that there is - for some reason - a (syntactic or semantic) problem with your SQL query, so that `mysql_query` returns `FALSE` instead of a MySQL result resource.

You can use `mysql_error()` to retrieve the error message from MySQL as string for debugging.

---

Please note, that the `mysql` extension you're using is deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and will be removed in future releases of PHP. Consider switching to [`mysqli`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 1):

Your query probably returns `FALSE` because of an error.

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

[**Source**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

`var_dump()` your `$out` to see if it's `FALSE`.

And even better, just display your error to debug:

```
if (!$out) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}
```

BTW, you shouldn't use `mysql_query()` and all other `mysql_*` functions anymore as they are **deprecated**. Use [**mysqli**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or **[PDO](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** instead.